# Create line segment in Three.js with 2D shapes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using Three.js to render the graphical representation of a [gerber file](https://www.ucamco.com/en/file-formats/gerber/downloads).

The specification allows you to render lines with either a circular or rectangular "aperture".

The result with a circular aperture should have round endings.  The result with a rectangle is dependent on the orientation of the aperture as described in the specification.

The specification gives the following example images to illustrate.

[image: Aligned Stroke]

[image: Unaligned Stroke]

What would be the best way to achieve this in Three.js?

The gerber specification further limits arcs to only being drawn with circular apertures, but assuming someone wanted to draw line segments in any arbitrary 2D shape what would be the best approach?

I know in 3D to perform a union it would probably be best to use [Constructive Solid Geometry](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/).  I assume I could do the same in 2D by simply using an extruded form of the shape, but I would prefer to remain in 2D if possible.

The gerber format is basically just a binary rendering with Dark and Clear draw operations which either draw (Dark) or erase (Clear) what is being stroked.  I figure the easiest way to achieve this would be to pick two colors (BG color and Shape color) and just draw primitives one after another with the most recent drawn on top.  I figured this would be easier to manage restricting to 2D only.  If someone has a better suggestion I would be interested to hear that as well.

Comment: You state "I am using Three.js to render the graphical representation of a gerber file." Can you share the code you have so far that accomplishes this? It may be you have the best way already. The format specification looks very non-trivial. If I were you, I'd start here: https://github.com/mcous/gerber-parser/blob/master/API.md and from the standard Gerber Shape types, create methods which take gerber specific parameters such as circle diameter and position to literally draw a circle with the proper diameter.

Comment: I actually already implemented the parser :).  I use regex pattern matching and a stateful parser which sounds similar to the approach taken in that project you reference.  I already build an intermediate AST from this data that I can operate on each command how I wish.  Thanks for the suggestion though I didn't see that project prior to rolling my own :P.  As for the code... It doesn't belong to me so I can't really share it.  The question is more so specifically focused on methods in Three.js to draw swept shapes.

Comment: It's sort of like spreading a deck of cards out on a table. The aperture defines the printing, hence the need for arcs to be circles. got it. Interesting. Three.js DOES support SVG, there is an SVG Loader in the examples folder in the three git repo. There is also an open source javascript gerber to svg converter @ https://github.com/mcous/gerber-to-svg/blob/master/API.md But this assumes you just need to display a gerber, not draw/edit/print one.